# I have changed the package name of my app but on Firebase, it is still the previous one. Please see details

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I decided to change my app's package name and changed it using this tactic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/6144372 and then manually changed the package name defined in `google-services.json` file under this tag: `"package_name": "com.xxx.xxx"`, but when I saw the package name in the Settings section of Firebase Console, it still shows the old one there.

So, I wanted to know that will it cause some bad effect on my app's performance in future or will it not do any harm? Please let me know

And if there is some way of changing the package name in Firebase Console settings too, let me know that too.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider creating a new Firebase project. Just delete the old project and create a new one, with your new package name. I am not sure about the performance issues of just changing the old `google-services.json` file, but creating a new project is certainly more secure to prevent any future issues.

UPDATE: Thanks to TommieC.'s comment, a better way would be to add a new app to the project and just delete the old app. The new app will have your updated package name. Then download the `google-services.json` and replace it with the old file. 
This method would be safer, in case your firebase project already has different integrations and deleting it is not really an option.

Comment: Actually one can keep the existing project, while just adding a new app with the updated bundle. The old app can be deleted under the project. Download and overwrite the google-services file and use as before. This way the db reference doesn't need to change.

Comment: @TommieC. I didn't know of that way too. Your way seems more legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises when your firebase package name and application ID doesnot match. There is no any rename features in firebase project. You should create the new firebase project that matches the application Id and delete the old project. Then just import respective firebase project json to your code project. That should do the trick